# react-native, react-hook-form: FormProvider as HOC

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I am new in react-hook-form, and my question, that when I wrap my whole application with FormProvider can I access the state like the react context API, or the redux provider or this component is just for inject the useform methods into the context for calling everywhere?

My case is that I have a react-native application. I wrapped my app into the FormProvider in the App.tsx. I have a form screen where I have to add some data from another screen (react-native-screens). So I tried to call getValues and setValue on the new screen but I get undefined as a result of the getValues method.
Should I create custom react context with useEffect to update the form state or there is chance to solve this with useFormContext hook?

Answer (score 1):

Hello first you don't need react-hook-form as a global state supplier . use redux it's much simpler as to your appProvider you simply import Provider from 'react-redux' then pass the store as a prop then configure your store to take injectable states from future containers  . react-hook-forms main roll is meant to handle forms : check their usage https://react-hook-form.com .  i use it mainly in authentification containers to control the flow of data that is to be sent to the main store.  . i hope this answer gives you some clarity .

Comment: I use redux and its all features, but my question is the FormProvider store the form state globally or not?

Comment: technically yes according to their definition  anyway [Link](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#FormProviderPerformance)   but it comes at  performance  price you will need to wrap every component that depends on it  in a memo .  and ye it behaves as a global state for nested component forms ONLY. sorry i didn't understand your question first .  but the answer yes .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly ,in order to accessing your states anywhere in functional components by **redux** you are able to use **useSelector** for getting data and **useDispatch** for dispatching data. Also in the react context you capable of to creating your *custom hook* for easier accessing to your states by **useContext** or directly use that and for setting your states you can use **useReducer** (better way) or set in the context.

[React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

[Redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)

Comment: The exact question is that the FormProvider wrapper in react-hook-form can work as the redux provider.